# Find a line perpendicular to another line, intersecting a line and going through a point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Find a line going through a point $A(2,3,1)$ perpendicular to $l: x=1+2t; \ y=3+2t;\ z=-t$ and interesecting line $k: x=y=z$.

The direction vector of the line we are looking for show be orthogonal to vector $[2,2,-1]$. For example direction vector of this line is $[-2,2,0]$. And then we acheive intersection with $k$ by taking the point (for example) $(1,1,1)$. So the line is: $x=1-2t;\ y=1+t;\ z=1$. Is it correct?

Comment: You can't take a direction vector and a point arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the line meets $k$ and $(s,s,s)$. Then $(s-2,s-3,s-1)$ is perpendicular to $(2,2,-1)$. Find $s$ by considering the dot product.